# Determine if on product page programmatically in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to insert tracking codes on all of the pages of a Magento site, and need to use a different syntax if the page is a CMS page, a category browsing page, or a product view page. I have a custom module set up with a block that inserts a generic tracking code on each page for now. From within the block, how can I distinguish between CMS pages, category pages, and product pages?

I started with:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest();
```

I can see that

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

returns the product or category ID on product and category pages, but doesn't distinguish between those page types.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

return "cms" for CMS pages, but returns "catalog" for both category browsing and product view pages, so I can't use that to tell category and product pages apart.

Is there some indicator in the request I can use safely? Or is there a better way to accomplish my goal of different tracking codes for different page types?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There may be an even better way to do this using routers, but one fast way is to check the registry to see if we have a single product that we are looking at:

```
<?php

$onCatalog = false;
if(Mage::registry('current_product')) {
    $onCatalog = true;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: It is possible situation when you have that registry key on custom pages or custom functionality. That 's why I don't recommend determine it with registry key. The way with controller name is better.

Comment: controller together with registry way is the best.

if you are using controller, and this block is present in your head.phtml, you might get problems on Tag pages(just met this issue) - Tag pages use Product controller, but cannot pull up Product data. So I use both conditions.

Answer (score 32):

The easest answer is the following:

```
<?php
echo $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
if($this->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='product') //do something
if($this->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='category') //do others
?>
```

this is 100% the right way to do according to the MVC model, please look into the core code really understand it, and do not give the method with loading or depends on the registry method. Support mytraining.net even though I am not there.

Comment: In some contexts, getRequest or getControllerName may be unavailable. You can call the underlying function directly. `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName()`

Answer (score 16):

I thought it would be worth mentioning there is a flaw to checking

```
Mage::registry('current_product')
```

This does indeed check if a product exists, but when on a review page for example, the product is also set, therefore you may need to be more specific to determine the page location.

The following check ensures we are on a product page, by checking it is using the "catalog" module, and the controller is a "product" request. When viewing a products list of reviews it's values would be "review" (module) and "list" (controller).

```
if($this->getRequest()->getModuleName()=='catalog' && 
$this->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='product'){
    Mage::registry('current_product');
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a parameter to the block being used to indicate what type of tracking code is needed. Then you just use the layout XML to solve the problem.  You can use the following layout handles to have your block updated with the proper parameter:
CMS Pages = 'cms_page'
Category browsing = 'catalog_category_view'
Product viewing = 'catalog_product_view'

Something like this:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="mymodule/myblock" name="myblock" />
        </reference>
    </default>
    <cms_page>
        <reference name="myblock">
            <action method="setTrackingType">
                <type>cms</type>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="myblock">
            <action method="setTrackingType">
                <type>category</type>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="myblock">
            <action method="setTrackingType">
                <type>product</type>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: How can i use those please ?