# Determine type of product page the user is on

Tags: magento

I was looking at the answer here and it gets me 75% of the way there, however, is there a way to distinguish between a bundle product versus a simple product?

[Determine if on product page programmatically in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041510/determine-if-on-product-page-programmatically-in-magento)

Running Magento 1.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch ($product->getTypeId()) {
    case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE:
        //...
        break;
    case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE:
        //...
        break;
    case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE:
        //...
        break;
    case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED:
        //...
        break;
    case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL:
        //...
        break;
}
```