# Magento 2 Product Type static value

Tags: magento2

I need the same answer of this question
[Determine type of product page the user is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680058/determine-type-of-product-page-the-user-is-on)

Only I need it for Magento 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly than you're just looking for a way to differentiate between Product type that means you already have a product along with product type, and you want to add some functionality to the page on the basis of `ProductType`. So, for that you can easily get product types from `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type`.

But, in Magento 2 configurable and grouped products are in different modules as you can see below.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type as ProductType;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable as ConfigurableType;
use Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped as GroupedType;

switch ($product->getTypeId()) {
    case ProductType::TYPE_SIMPLE:
        // ....
        break;
    case ProductType::TYPE_BUNDLE:
        // ....
        break;
    case ProductType::TYPE_VIRTUAL:
        // ....
        break;
    case ConfigurableType::TYPE_CODE:
        // ....
        break;
    case GroupedType::TYPE_CODE:
        // ....
        break;
}
```

I haven't checked the above code but it should work!