# How to select the pages type where my block will be displayed (cms, product, category)?

Tags: magento, block, layer

I am working on a slider block Magento, and I want to be able to select where to display it in the Front.

Is it possble to select the type of pages fromo (cms, product, category) ?

Need Help :) 
Thanks !

Comment: where do you want to make the selection on where to display the block?
e.g. within the template file? within the CMS block in the magento backend? in the XML?

Comment: in my backend Grid/Form with a dropdown list .

Comment: Hello i think you can give this functionality in admin as dropdown list

Answer (score 1):

I like the way Lee Saferite [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041510/determine-if-on-product-page-programmatically-in-magento/7249805#7249805): to add your own type parameters in module layout

Comment: can you explain it a little more please ! 
how can i choose from those differents layout params ? THX

Comment: your should create method setTrackingType($type) {...} This method will return current page - cms, catalog or product page

Comment: But I want to choose in wich page i'll display my block .

Comment: you create custom form with a select box with values cms, category, product, inject block with slider to all pages and in block method check if user allowed to show slider on this page.