# magento detecting product page programmatically

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

On an observer file I need to detect if the loaded page corresponds to a product. I've been using a similar method to the one used on the [checked answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041796/1297603):

```
if (!(Mage::registry('current_product'))) return;
```

But until now we were testing on development. From today we are testing on pre-production servers, with lot of modules and plugins. Until now it worked seamesly but now it does not work, it does not detect when a product page is loaded. I think is related with the url rewrite to show a more "friendly" url's but can not detect how to solve it. I took a look into Alan Storm tutorial [In Depth Magento Dispatch](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch) but I still can get what is wrong or what do I need to change.

Any idea? Or some other solution on how to detect when a product page is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've verified that the observer is being hit?  Make sure that for the event you are triggering on has a unique name for that event.  For example in the following code the name "catalog_product_set_price" must be unique in regards to "catalog_product_load_after" event.  I'm assuming you're getting into the observer, but just in case.  This risk becomes possible if you add a bunch of new modules to an instance.

```
        <catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <catalog_product_set_price>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>NamespaceModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>set_price2</method>
                </catalog_product_set_price>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_load_after>
```

You could use the following array to check where you are:

```
$currentPageArray = array(
            'request_string'=> Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRequestString(),
            'uri'           => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRequestUri(),
            'route'         => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName(),
            'action'        => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getActionName(),
            'controller'    => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName()
        );
```

it will output something like:

```
Array
(
    [request_string] => /some-category/some-product-page-url.html
    [uri] => /catalog/product/view/id/64806/category/17
    [route] => catalog
    [action] => view
    [controller] => product
)
```

You could try a different observer.

- controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_product_view
- controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_view

Comment: Nice answer, got an upvote just for the detailed information. Yes, the observer is being hit, that is not an issue. At the same time you posted your answer I was precisely testing the use of the 'Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName()' and it works indeed. I will also try to test using the observer suggested at the end.